# In run method, how to find from where start was called?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am debugging some code. My debugger shows that the origin of code is from Thread.run(). I need to know from which part of code Thread.start() was called! Is there a way to find this out?

Comment: Which ide are you using?

Comment: using Eclipse Sir.. but I guess JVM needs to give some sort of support.. maybe some VM arg (?)

Comment: If there are not too many threads in your application, you can also set a breakpoint on Thread.start() and evaluate other variables to discern if it is the right Thread being started.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `new Throwable().getStackTrace()` to get a full stack trace. To get the `start` stack you must extend `Thread`, one of the few times it is actually necessary to do so (mostly using `Runnable` is preferred).

```
class C extends Thread {
    StackTraceElement[] constructed;
    StackTraceElement[] started;

    public C() {
        constructed = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your suuff.
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void start() {
        started = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
        super.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a crude and effective technique using Eclipse or any other IDE. Suppose you have a breakpoint in your Runnable or Callable, and thread pauses there... indeed, one can't figure out from where start was called right away... *but*, just right click Runnable/Callable constructor and click 'show call hierarchy'.. that's it!! You will come to know where the Runnable/Callable was constructed.. and start is called right after that!
In Eclipse, if Runnable/Callable has no no-arg constructor, right click on class name and select 'show call hierarchy'.. problem solved.. what a relief.